# Using Android internal drawables

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm trying to write a tristate switch. But I'm failing to access the default [com.android.internal.R.styleable.Switch_track](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#Switch_track) drawable to use as background.

How to get that drawable?

Is there another approach for getting the default background?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not access private resources, you can't be sure that the resource will be available on all devices. And even if it is available, you can't be sure it will be the same.

If you want to use a private resource, you have to copy it into your project resources from SDK or Android sources.

Comment: ok, sounds reasonable. But I also can't find the Switch_track drawable in the sources.. do you?

Comment: Well, you won't find `Switch_track`, this name denotes that `Switch` widget has `android:track` attribute. Then you can find in `styles.xml` that the attribute refers to drawables such as `switch_track_holo_light` (it depends on the theme).

Answer (score 5):

Just for reference:
While it is not advised to access internal resources and you should be aware, that they can change or could be removed by a vendor or with an OS update, it is possible to access them at runtime:

```
int id = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("Switch_track", "styleable", "android");
```

Comment: This is incorrect. getIdentifier returns an int while a styleable is an int array. I believe the only way that this can be done is by using reflection http://stackoverflow.com/a/13841530/3508192

Comment: Sorry, correction, styleable is sometimes an int array