# Accessing <declare-styleable> resources programmatically

Tags: android

Is it possible to receive the resource-ids being kept by a as an int[] programmatically without referring to the resource-class R?

```
<declare-styleable name="com_facebook_login_view">
    <attr name="confirm_logout" format="boolean"/>
    <attr name="fetch_user_info" format="boolean"/>
    <attr name="login_text" format="string"/>
    <attr name="logout_text" format="string"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

The problem is that I cannot resolve the ID of the defined 'declare-styleable' attribute - 0x00 is always returned:

```
int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier( "com_facebook_login_view", "declare-styleable", context.getPackageName() ); 
int[] resourceIDs = context.getResources().getIntArray( id );
```

Comment: that's because it is a declare-styleable, not an identifier. Did you try reflection on the R.styleable class ?

Comment: No I didn't mention this - thanks for the hint - 
I'll try it using reflection :)
So there is no way to access a declare-styleable dynamically?

I would use it for the method

getContext().obtainStyledAttributes( AttributeSet set, int[] attrs );

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Solved it. But my reputation is too low to answer my own question :(
I'll post it in eight hours if it doesn't fall into oblivion. ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is the solution that delivers the resource-IDs programmatically for the `child-<attr>-tags` defined for a `<declare-styleable>` tag:

```
/*********************************************************************************
*   Returns the resource-IDs for all attributes specified in the
*   given <declare-styleable>-resource tag as an int array.
*
*   @param  context     The current application context.
*   @param  name        The name of the <declare-styleable>-resource-tag to pick.
*   @return             All resource-IDs of the child-attributes for the given
*                       <declare-styleable>-resource or <code>null</code> if
*                       this tag could not be found or an error occured.
*********************************************************************************/
public static final int[] getResourceDeclareStyleableIntArray( Context context, String name )
{
    try
    {
        //use reflection to access the resource class
        Field[] fields2 = Class.forName( context.getPackageName() + ".R$styleable" ).getFields();

        //browse all fields
        for ( Field f : fields2 )
        {
            //pick matching field
            if ( f.getName().equals( name ) )
            {
                //return as int array
                int[] ret = (int[])f.get( null );
                return ret;
            }
        }
    }
    catch ( Throwable t )
    {
    }

    return null;
}
```

Maybe this could help somebody one day.

Comment: It must be the accepted answer as it provides a 100% R.styleable independent solution.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more efficient solution:

```
public static final int[] getResourceDeclareStyleableIntArray(String name) {
        Field[] allFields = R.styleable.class.getFields();
        for (Field field : allFields) {
            if (name.equals(field.getName())) {
                try {
                    return (int[]) field.get(R.styleable.class);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ignore) {}
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final int[] getResourceDeclareStyleableIntArray(String name) {
    int[] result = null;
    try {
        result = (int[]) R.styleable.class.getField(name).get(R.styleable.class);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```