# Can't access R.class from Unity Android project

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm have an Android library that I'm now building a Unity3D plugin for. The Android library performs reflection on the R.Styleable class to retrieve data on a 'declare-styleable' resource to achieve something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13841530/1375067).

The first step is the following:

```
Field[] fields = Class.forName( context.getPackageName() + ".R$styleable" ).getFields();
```

The above line executes no problem when the library is run as part of a native Android project in Eclipse. However, when run through a Unity Android app, it throws a NoClassDefFoundError.
(same happens if you replace ".R&$styleable" with simply ".R" above).

I've read many accounts that Unity does not generate a R.class file. Is this true? I know that a R.java file is generated in Unity's "StagingArea/gen" folder, at least. If so, is there no other way to dynamically access resources in a Unity Android project than through Context.getResources()?

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code.

```
final R.drawable drawableResources = new R.drawable();
        final Class<R.drawable> c = R.drawable.class;
        final Field[] fields = c.getDeclaredFields();
        int resourceId;
        for (Field field : fields) {
            try {
                resourceId = field.getInt(drawableResources);
                //TODO do something
            } catch (Exception e) {
                continue;
            }
        }
```