# Android Resources.getIdentifier returns wrong value for Custom Attribute

Tags: android, xml, android-custom-attributes

Recently I was working on a project that use `Resources.getIdentifier()` a lot. All works fun but problems come out when I try to use this method to retrieve on custom attributes.

So I declare some attributes int the xml

```
<declare-styleable name="WemeFloatExpandMenuItem">
    <attr name="label" format="string|reference"/>
    <attr name="icon" format="reference"/>
    <attr name="showDot" format="boolean"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Then I apply this attribute in xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="36dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:divider="@drawable/weme_float_menu_divider"
    android:background="@drawable/weme_float_menu_bg">
    <com.weme.chat.FloatExpandMenuItem 
        android:id="@id/wemepay_float_menu_account"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:label="@string/wemepay_float_menu_title_account"
        app:icon="@drawable/weme_float_menu_account"/>
```

In FloatExpandMenuItem

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, ResourceUtils.getResIds(getContext().getPackageName(), "styleable", "WemeFloatExpandMenuItem"));
labelRes = a.getString(ResourceUtils.getResId(getContext(),"styleable","WemeFloatExpandMenuItem_label"));
iconRes = a.getDrawable(ResourceUtils.getResId(getContext(), "styleable", "WemeFloatExpandMenuItem_icon"));
showDot = a.getBoolean(ResourceUtils.getResId(getContext(), "styleable", "WemeFloatExpandMenuItem_showDot"), false);        
a.recycle();
```

ResourceUtils.getResId was wrapper for Resources.getIdentifier like this

```
public static int getResId(Context context, String resTypeName, String resName) {
    if (context == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    String packageName = context.getPackageName();
    return res.getIdentifier(resName, resTypeName, packageName);
}
```

**And weird things happened, I tried to debug in FloatExpandMenuItem , the ResourceUtils.getResId always return 0 when retrieve the label,icon,showDot attributes.**

So I was wondering how I should change the code when I try to deal with custom attributes when using Resources.getIdentifier() ?

Comment: Maybe this will help You:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816596/accessing-declare-styleable-resources-programatically

Comment: @R.Zagórski Reflection is our final solution and we manage to do that if we cannot solve this problem before deadline. But I was wondering why custom attributes not working on this method or am I using this method in a wrong way ?